# Text/resource with information on all skeletal muscles and their motor units

Tags: neuroscience, anatomy, muscles

Something analogous to an encyclopedia on baseball players with a list of all thier stats would be ideal.

I'm not looking for just generic muscle names, locations and illustrations.

Good answers would include links to resources, textbooks etc. which include stats for most or all of the following of every skeletal muscle in the human anatomy:

- Language of origin/LOO definition
- Labeled by ? shape, location, size etc.
- Type of Shape (i.e., fusiform, pennate, bipennate, multipennate, convergent, parrellel etc)
- Angle(s) of pennation (if applicable)
- # of motor neuron innervations
- # of proprioceptors in muscle
- # of fibers
- Length of muscle
- Length of fibers
- Typical fuel system reliance (determined off of biomechanical placement and architecture..CPr, oxidative, etc.)
- Biomechanical function (structure of corresponding bone/tendon anchors and corresponding movement manipulation)

Comment: I'm not inclined to think that there is a "Compendium of All Muscle Data" out there, unfortunately.  I'm looking forward to an answer as well if there is.  Much of the insertion point, etc. data can probably be found in any medical anatomy text, but the fiber/fusiform/spindle/motor unit data may not be readily available for humans in one place.  I know Robert E. Burke at the NIH has devoted an entire successful career to exploring the motor unit anatomy and physiology of the cat preparation.  A pubmed search should give you a number of papers in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Biomechanical models used in software frameworks such as [OpenSim](https://simtk.org/home/opensim).

Here is an example of a combined upper and lower body model in XML: [ULB_Project](https://simtk.org/project/xml/downloads.xml?group_id=415#package_id684).